# Passing Coldfusion Form Values to javascript and CFC , code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I'm trying to pass my form values into a javascript function which would pass them into my CFC function for insertion into the database, but its not working. JS code is below:

Updated: removed "." in front of alert() and url:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#createReport").click(function(f) {
        var getReportName = $("input#reportName").val();
        var getReportPath = $("input#reportPath").val();
        var getReportDesc = $("input#reportDescrip").val();
        var getReportCategory = $("input#categoryBox").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "components/reportController.cfc?method=createReport&returnformat=json",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data:{ 
                    reportName: getReportName,
                    reportPath: getReportPath,
                    reportDescrip: getReportDesc,
                    categoryBox: getReportCategory
            },
            success: function(){
                alert("You successfully added a new report to the system") } 
});
    });
});
```

Coldfusion Form Code: (updated my form removing flash type and CFlayout)

```
 <cfform name="addReportForm"  height="400" width="500" enctype="multipart/form-data">                                              <!--- Form Initialization --->
 <p> Report Name </p>
   <cfinput type="Text" name="reportName" size="20"maxlength="35" label="Report Name"                               <!--- Report Name Field --->
    value="Report Name" required="yes" id="reportName">     
 <p> Report Path </p>   
 <cfinput type="Text" name="reportPath" size="20" maxlength="35" label="Report Path"                                <!--- Report Path Field ---> 
 value="Report Path" required="yes" id="reportPath"> 

 <!--- Report Category Dropdown box --->   
 <p> Category </p>
 <cfselect name="category" label="Category" id="categoryBox" message="Select Category"                              <!--- DB populated drop down box for reports. Required field. ---> 
 width="250" required="yes" tooltip="Select Category">                                                              <!--- Values are static for testing. CFSELECT to be populated by query--->
 <option value="Admin Tools">Admin Tools </option>                                                                
 <option value="Reports">Reports</option>
 <option value="Vendor Tools">Vendor Tools </option>
 <option value="Company Links">Company Links</option>
 <option value="Operations"> Operations</option>
 </cfselect>      
 <p> Report Description </p>    
  <cftextarea name="reportDescrip" size="20" maxlength="200" label="Report Description"
 value=" Enter Report Description" required="yes" id="reportDescrip" width="600" height="250">
 </cftextarea>
 <br />
 <br />
 <cfinput type="button" name="createReport" label="Add New Report" value="Add New Report" id="createReport"/>
 </cfform>
```

Cans someone tell me what I may be doing wrong that its not working.

Update: I opened up the IE console and the script has a SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier error for this line: 
**success: function(){

alert.("You successfully added a new report to the system") }**

update: Eliminated the CF flash forms and designated HTML as the form type in cfform. AJAX call still not working.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is you are using `cflayout` and `cfform`. While they may seem like a good solution...they are not. All the ColdFusion UI functionality is poorly implemented, uses outdated libraries and is woefully limited in functionality. Stick to plain old HTML forms and use something like Bootstrap for your layout.

Comment: I disagree with Matt's opinion. I see it in there. Best thing to do is open your browser's developer tools, check the console for JS errors and watch your network traffic when you submit your form. Also you need to correct your "category" object code. Right now it's looking for a "category" tag.

Scott says "What you are doing wrong"... well it's not wrong, but I don't suggest that either for the same reasons. But you will need to check your source code in the browser to verify how it changed things up if you do use them.

Comment: When you purposely use outdated, poorly implemented tools.....you are doing it wrong. :D

Comment: Also, you cannot simply say 'It is not working'. You need to tell us what you expected to happen and what actually happened, as well as any errors and what was returned from ColdFusion.

Comment: Try removing the `(` and `)` from around the value of `data` in your AJAX call.

Comment: You have a dot after alert.  alert.("You successfully added a new report to the system"). Remove the dot and try.

Comment: As @DG3 pointed, a `.` dot after `alert` may be the culprit.

Comment: There is another dot at start of url in ajax function. "./components..." Probably that would throw an another error.

Comment: I corrected both and the script isn't throwing an error, but its not sending the form values through JS to CFC to DB.

Comment: @Alex Update the code in the question to reflect the changes you made. This may be helpful for new visitors.

Comment: also, you are using $("category").val(); what is category? id or name...you need to prefix with a hash if it is an id....check your developer tools to see what is getting passed and what is getting returned...as suggested remove format="flash"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue which had to do with resolving the path to the cfc. Working code is below.

**Solution:**

**AJAX:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#createReport").click(function(f) {
            var getReportName = $("input#reportName").val();
            var getReportPath = $("input#reportPath").val();
            var getReportDesc = $("input#reportDescrip").val();
            //var getCategory   = $("input#categoryBox").val();


            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "http://10.11.2.60/testFolder/bidirectionalreporting/codetest/components/coldfusionFunction.cfc?method=testFunc&returnformat=json",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data:{ 
                        reportName: getReportName,
                        reportPath: getReportPath,
                        reportDescrip: getReportDesc
                        //categoryBox: getCategory

                },
                success: function(result){
                    alert("You successfully added a new report to the system") } 
    });
        });
    });


</script>
```

**Coldfusion:**

```
<!--- CF AJAX function to create new report in DB--->
    <cffunction name="testFunc"  access="remote" description="tests the AJAX functionality and query">     <!--- Function takes in variables from CF page and AJAX call --->
    <cfargument name="mathVariable" default="8978" type="any">                                             <!--- This is just a test argument to verify ajax works before adding new fields--->
    <cfargument name="reportName" default="" type="any">                                                   <!--- This argument maps to the like named form field and is passed through AJAX call--->                
    <cfargument name="reportPath" default="" type="any">                                                   <!--- This argument maps to the like named form field and is passed through AJAX call--->
    <cfargument name="reportDescrip"  default="" type="any" >                                              <!--- This argument maps to the like named form field and is passed through AJAX call--->
    <cfargument name="categoryBox" default="Vendor Management" type="any">                                 <!--- This argument maps to the like named form field and is passed through AJAX call--->

    <cfquery name="qryTest" datasource="First_Title_Main_Dev">                                              <!--- Query creates a new report in the master report list table--->
     INSERT INTO Report_Master_List (Report_Name, URL, Report_Desc, Category)

         VALUES (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.reportName#">,                  <!--- report name form field references Report_Name column--->
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.reportPath#">,                   <!--- report path form field references ReportPath column--->
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.reportDescrip#">,                <!--- report descrip form field references ReportDescrip column --->
</cffunction
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code you have `format="flash"` on your `cfform`. This will render the form using flash not HTML. As such, jQuery can not read the form values as there are no HTML form elements. If you change it to `format="html"` then at least you'll have an HTML form and then you can start to dig into the JavaScript code and fix those issues.

The only only thing to look out for is in your jQuery code. Make sure if you use the `#` sign you are not inside a `cfoutput` block else the Javascript will not render as you expect.